# Bind tmpl to a jquery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates

Can anyone explain this behavior, imagine you have a jQuery collection, like this:

```
var list = $("#mySelect").children().filter(":selected");
```

Then I want to create a text-join to get "pX, pY" by using the following template:

```
var concatenation = $.tmpl("p${$data.val()}, ", list);
```

Result is a text node with only the first value in list "pX,".

Of course there are other ways to solve this example, eg.

```
"p" + $("#mySelect").val().join(", p");
```

With some trimming. But my question is about the tmpl behaviour, I don't understand why it only takes the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your options is a jQuery selector result collection, it looks like the template engine does not understand that this is a collection and databind one row to the entire collection, thats why $data.val() return the first value (Thats the deafault behavior of a jquery selector).

If you instead do

```
var concatenation = $.tmpl("p${$data.value}, ", options.get());
```

.get() will return the underlying DOM elements as an array, the template engine as no problem databind against these. Dont forget that you need to change your template from $data.val() to $data.value since you are now working directly against the DOM element

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry I renamed "options" to "list", if someone is confused by this). Shouldn't a jQuery collection be a valid input though???